# Проблема с цикличным импортом

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, импорт

В первом файле у меня импортируется второй файл:

```
from AsyncLolz.api.methods import Get

class SimpleLolzApi:
    def __init__(
            self,
            token: str
    ):
        self.token = token
        self.api = Get()
```

Но в это же время, в этом втором файле, происходит наследование класса из первого файла:

```
from AsyncLolz.auth import SimpleLolzApi

class Get(SimpleLolzApi):
    ...
```

Как быть? Без наследования класса из первого файла не обойтись, потому что второй файл использует переменную `token`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from AsyncLolz.api.methods import Get

class SimpleLolzApi:
    def __init__(
            self,
            token: str
    ):
        self.token = token
        self.api = Get(self.token)      # + self.token
```

**methods.py**

```
class Get():
    def __init__(self, token: str):
    ...
```